# I need ReactDOM.render to render each time its called

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on an app that will be going inside another web application. I need ReactDOM.render to re-render my app each time the focus function is called. Right now it only renders it once but then each time after that it does not re-render it. Focus is called each time a user enters my app, so I need react to re-render each time to stay updated.

```
focus: function (freshApi, freshState) {
      // show main content
      // elAddin.className = elAddin.className.replace('hidden', '').trim();
      console.log('test');
      var elAddin = document.getElementById('customFuelTracker');
      ReactDOM.render(<App geotabApi={freshApi} geotabState={freshState} appName={'customFuelTracker'} />, elAddin);    
    },
```

I've tried erasing the innerHTML of the container on exit, but that still requires a page refresh to reload react.

Comment: Make that a prop that can be passed to your `App`, and export your app _as a React component_ so that other apps can just stick your app inside their app?

Comment: The parent website is not using react unfortunately, so I do not think I could do that. I'm having to build this and inject.

Comment: In that case remember that your app is also still just "plain JS" so there's nothing preventing you from adding a `focus` event listener in your app and have that trigger a render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `unmountComponentAtNode`

```
focus: function (freshApi, freshState) {
      // show main content
      // elAddin.className = elAddin.className.replace('hidden', '').trim();
      console.log('test');
      var elAddin = document.getElementById('customFuelTracker')
      ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(elAdmin)
      ReactDOM.render(<App geotabApi={freshApi} geotabState={freshState} appName={'customFuelTracker'} />, elAddin);    
    },
```